# Python -- ranking values in array based on corresponding masked array

Tags: python, scipy

I have two different arrays:

```
values = [[ NaN   3.46677628e+01   2.39846527e+02   6.50530212e+02
    1.75084473e+03]
 [  1.02219486e+01   8.44505539e+01   1.38439526e+03   4.25593896e+03
    4.07225195e+03]
 [  2.91582775e+01   1.73292007e+02   9.09395752e+02   1.85212927e+03
    1.12369495e+03]
 [  1.88855534e+01   6.51165543e+01   1.62291489e+02   1.30152039e+02
    9.58973465e+01]]
```

and

```
condition = [[0 1 1 1 1]
 [1 1 3 3 1]
 [1 1 3 3 1]
 [1 1 1 1 1]]
```

I am wanting to use `condition` to create a mask of `values` so that I can perform an operation only on the entries of `values` that are `1`.  I've created the mask successfully, but I'm not sure how to perform the operation I want, as described.

The operation is ranking the entries of `values` using `scipy.stats.rank(???, method = 'ordinal')`, where I am using `???` to indicate that I'm not sure what to put in that place.  If I wanted to rank the entries without the mask, I know I would put `values` where I have `???`, but I don't want to rank the non-1-valued entries of `values`.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to first create the relevant array, for example with

```
relevant = [[val[i] for i in range(len(val)) if cond[i]==1] for (val, cond) in zip(values, conditions)]
```

And then apply your sorting algorithm.
If you wanted to sort all values in one go, you can flatten you list with:

```
relevant = [x for m in relevant for x in m]
```

So this would give you:

```
>>> values = [[ 0.1, 3.46677628,   2.39846527,   6.50530212, 1.7508447], [  1.02219486 ,  8.44505539  , 1.38439526  , 4.25593896 ]]
>>> conditions = [[0,1,1,1,1],[1133]]
>>> relevant = [[val[i] for i in range(len(val)) if cond[i]==1] for (val,  cond) in zip(values, conditions)]
>>> relevant
[[3.46677628, 2.39846527, 6.50530212, 1.7508447], [1.02219486, 8.44505539]]
>>> relevant = [x for m in relevant for x in m]
>>> relevant
[3.46677628, 2.39846527, 6.50530212, 1.7508447, 1.02219486, 8.44505539]
```

Comment: Is this pseudo-code, or was this meant to be a working example to try within my code?

Comment: This is a working example (I corrected an error and added an example use)

Answer (score 1):

You could loop through the sublists to build a new list, and pass that to rank()

```
rank_list=[]
for condition_index, sublist in enumerate(condition):
    for sublist_index, mask in enumerate(sublist):
        If mask==1:
            rank_list.append(values[condition_index][sublist_index])
return scipy.stats.rankdata(rank_list, method="ordinal")
```

Comment: Would this result in rank_list having the same dimensions as the original arrays?  I absolutely must maintain the original relative locations of the entries in the respective arrays.

Comment: No.  The dimensions would change. You should See if the pandas library is a better fit for you.

Comment: Oh, that's unfortunate.  Okay, I'll check pandas.  Thank you!